# Sencha Touch 2 : How to hide the addressbar for Android devices?

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Background:

I am developing a mobile web for Android - Galaxy Tab and I want to hide the addressbar as soon as the user enters the app.

```
viewport: 
{ autoMaximize : true}
```

does not work for Android devices ( I have tested this).

I have tested below code on my view.

```
initialize: function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,1);
    this.callParent();
    this.hideAddressBar();
},


hideAddressBar : function()
{
    if(document.documentElement.scrollHeight<window.outerHeight/window.devicePixelRatio)
        document.documentElement.style.height=(window.outerHeight/window.devicePixelRatio)+'px';
    setTimeout(window.scrollTo(1,1),0);
}
```

And I have made below settings in the Android 'Internet' browser.

***-> Disable the zoom
-> Set Automaximize to true.***

What happens is, I have to manually click on the top tab above address bar and then only the address bar is getting  hidden. Is there any way I can achieve this thru code?

Other interesting fact is, this happens only on 'Internet' browser and not on Google Chrome. If somebody was able to accomplish this functionality in a particular browser then please throw some ideas.

Comment: did you try to spell autoMaximize with a capital M ?

Comment: Yes, It was a type error in the post :( . Sorry for that. I tried with  viewport: {
        autoMaximize: true
    }, but it did not work on Android devices where as it worked on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile browser currently don't support the fullscreen API
http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

On iOS devices however you can achieve a fullscreen view with 

adding the app to your homescreen and starting from there.

On my galaxy tab 2 i have enabled the quick controls in the stock browser to achieve fullscreen view.

Maybe you can fake a hidden address bar, take a look at this
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/